# change margin for <br> <div> and <span> in wkwebview kit in objective c

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I wanted to reduce the space in the HTML string.
below is the code is am using

```
  NSString *headerString = @"<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'></header>";
    headerString = [headerString stringByAppendingString:htmlstring];
    headerString = [headerString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br><br/><br/><br><br/><br/>" withString:@"<br><br/>"];
    headerString = [headerString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br><br/><br><br/>" withString:@"<br><br/>"];
 [webviewkit loadHTMLString:headerString baseURL:nil];
```

I had also tried using Javascript but i am not sure what exactly the java script i should passed which will only give 1line spacing instead of mulitple line spacing :

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
 [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.open();document.close()" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable stringresult, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"result=>%@ error->%@",stringresult,error);
    }];
}
```

But i am not able to remove the spacing properly.

```
<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'></header><div><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial;">Hello and welcome to XYZ session!&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br><br/><span style="font-family: Arial;">Over the next three Hello world.&nbsp; Spacing takes alot of spaces over here due to span , br and div tags.</span><br><br/><span style="font-family: Arial;">Thank you again for agreeing to participate and helping the discussion....</span><br><br/><span style="font-family: Arial;">Over here,</span><br><br/></span></div><br/><ul><br/>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">I will be posting questions over here in stack overflow&nbsp;</span><br><br/>    </span></li><br/>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Throughout the day I will read everyone's responses and sometimes respond with my own follow-up questions.&nbsp;</span><br><br/>    </span></li><br/>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Please be i request to provide the code in objective c</span><br><br/>    </span></li><br/>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. &nbsp;</span><br><br/>    </span></li><br/>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span><br><br/>    </span></li><br/>    <li><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span></li><br/></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be slightly confused about `<br>` tags.  `<br>` or `<br />` are self-closing/void elements/empty tags:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp (under the empty html section)
http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html

> `<br>` is an empty element without a closing tag (the `<br>` tag defines a line break):

So when you're subbing in `<br><br />` you're actually subbing in two line breaks.  From your description it sounds as if you only want one line break, so you'll want to remove one of them.